# Can a 2nd-level sorcerer use sorcery points to create a 2nd-level spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, spell-slots

If a player is a 2nd-level sorcerer, and sacrifices one of their 1st-level spell slots to get an additional sorcery point, could they use their 3 sorcery points to create another 2nd-level spell slot?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for additional guidance. When you say "spell" do you mean "spell-slot"? Or are you asking if you gain a new spell? Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## No

The rules state:

> You can never have more sorcery points than shown on the table for your level. You regain all spent sorcery points when you finish a long rest.

At level 2, your maximum number of sorcery points is 2 (the value is always equal to your level from level 2 onwards). It takes 3 sorcery points to make a level 2 spell slot, so it is impossible.